# What is the actual usable message size in GCM (4kb or less?)

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am using GCM server library to send the messages from my server.

```
    message = new Message.Builder()
    .timeToLive(10)
    .delayWhileIdle(false)
    .addData("json", sendMsgData)
    .build();
```

As GCM supports 4kb message size, I would like to know **what is the actual size a sendMsgData can be of?**

 Is 4kb allowed on **sendMsgData** or are there other factors that I need to count and reduce my actual sendMsgData size?

Please refer following from the google documentation below, **if** the json below is subject to the limit of 4kb, **then** the actual message of the user which is "data" below will be less than 4kb...

Here is the example of a JSON-formatted request that includes TTL on google gcm doc site:

```
{
  "collapse_key" : "demo",
  "delay_while_idle" : true,
  "registration_ids" : ["xyz"],
  "data" : {
    "key1" : "value1",
    "key2" : "value2",
  },
  "time_to_live" : 3
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the lengths of the keys and values inside the "data" element count toward the 4096 bytes limit. The predefined keys (such as "collapse_key", "registration_ids", etc...) and their values don't count.

The last time I tested this limit (which was a couple of years ago), it seemed that it wasn't even a 4096 bytes limit, but 4096 character limit, which is a higher limit (since you can use, for example, 4096 characters of a non-English language that take more than one byte each).

I have to admit, though, that I didn't test this limit with a JSON content type. I tested it with a URL encoded content.